# Obtaining Values from a List-Dictionary Hybrid List Dynamically

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am currently trying to grab the values of certain fields of JSON documents received from a MongoDB query. The query returns a dictionary, and by using `.values()` on the query, I get a list of the values. However, some values of this list are another list containing dictionaries. I'm trying to figure out the best way to dynamically get a list of just the values of both the values already in the list and the values of the dictionaries found in the sub-lists as well.

For instance, I have a list called `text_list`:

```
>>> text_list 
[[{u'field1': u'field1_value1', u'field2': u'field2_value1'},
  {u'field2': u'field2_value2'}],
 u'value1',
 u'value2']
```

I want to grab just the values: `field1_value1, field2_value1, field2_value2, value1, value2` from this list (and either put them in a new list, or just concatenate the values into one large string).

I want to do this process for multiple lists, but sometimes the lists have these extra dictionaries and other times they don't.
What would be the best (least computing intensive/quickest) method to grab just the values I'm looking for

I came up with the following method:

```
def concatenate_list(inList):
    outString = '' #empty string that the values will be added to
    for item in inList:
        if type(item) == list:
            for i in np.arange(len(item)):
                for subitem in item[i].values():
                    outString = outString+' '+subitem
        else:
            outString = outString+' '+item
    return outString

>>> concatenate_list(text_list)
u'field1_value1 field2_value1 field2_value2 value1 value2'
```

Which gives me the result I'm looking for, but there has to be a better method than this. I don't see this being very efficient when I have to run this function over thousands of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a recursive function, which can print the values, only if they are neither a list nor a dictionary, like this

```
>>> def rec_fetcher(obj):
...     if isinstance(obj, list):
...         for item in obj:
...             yield from rec_fetcher(item)
...     elif isinstance(obj, dict):
...         for item in obj:
...             yield from rec_fetcher(obj[item])
...     else:
...         yield obj
... 
>>> list(rec_fetcher(data))
['field1_value1', 'field2_value1', 'field2_value2', 'value1', 'value2']
```

**Note:** Dictionaries are unordered. So the values from dictionary may not be in the same position, as in the literal passed.

---

`yield from` is a Python 3.x thing. If you are using Python 2.7, you can simply iterate the recursive call and yield the data, like this

```
>>> def rec_fetcher(obj):
...     if isinstance(obj, list):
...         for item in obj:
...             for value in rec_fetcher(item):
...                 yield value
...     elif isinstance(obj, dict):
...         for item in obj:
...             for value in rec_fetcher(obj[item]):
...                 yield value
...     else:
...         yield obj
... 
>>> list(rec_fetcher(data))
[u'field2_value1', u'field1_value1', u'field2_value2', u'value1', u'value2']
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot. And yeah, I'm using Python 2.7, I should have used that tag, my bad!

Comment: Apologies, it worked quite well! Thank you very much!